# How do I set up a Anti-XSS Exception Protection for Tumblr in NoScript?

Tags: noscript, tumblr

I use both the addon NoScript and the blogging platform Tumblr. In order to customise your blog's theme in Tumblr, it goes to [http://www.tumblr.com/customize] where it displays a live preview of the blog and any modifications made to the theme. Since NoScript prevents XSS, it sort of breaks the ability to modify one's theme in Tumblr, unless you click the "Unsafe Reload" function.

How can i set up a Anti-XSS Exception Protection in NoScript so that it safely disables XSS protection just for tumblr.com/customize? I've tried

```
^http://www.tumblr.com/(reblog|share|customize).*
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out. The exception I ended up going with is:

```
^http://([a-z]*)\.tumblr\.com/(reblog|share|customize|theme).*
```

Might not be the safest solution but it's the only one I could find that actually worked.